# Function to update a status flag for validity of other column?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, referential-integrity, check-constraints

How to create a function that compares `card_id` with `allowed_cards` array elements?
If it's in this array, column status must be updated to `TRUE`.

```
CREATE TABLE client_1 (
  id bigint NOT NULL,
  "time" timestamp without time zone DEFAULT now(),
  status boolean,
  card_id character varying(10),
  CONSTRAINT client_1_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE allowed_cards (
  allowed_cards character varying(10)[]
);

INSERT INTO allowed_cards VALUES ('{DD3234,FF2342}');
```

Comment: [So do you have your answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/169168)

Answer (score 1):

#### Enforce valid `card_id` at all times

First of all, ***if*** you need the table `card_allowed`, use a plain `varchar` or `text` column (with multiple entries), not an array:

```
CREATE TABLE card_allowed (
  card_id varchar(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);

INSERT INTO card_allowed VALUES ('DD3234'), ('FF2342');
```

Next, to ***enforce*** valid cards, you could now just use a [**FK constraint**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK):

```
CREATE TABLE client_1 (
  client_1_id  bigint NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  tstz         timestamptz DEFAULT now(),
  -- card_valid   boolean,
  card_id      varchar(10),
  CONSTRAINT client_1_card_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (card_id) REFERENCES card_allowed
);
```

Since the column can be NULL, you can always leave it empty if you don't have a valid `card_id`.

You don't need an additional column (you named it `status`, I renamed it `card_valid`).

I also changed some column names to make it more useful. Among other things, I am using the column name `tstz` instead of <strike>`time`</strike>, which is a reserved word in standard SQL and also very misleading for an actual `timestamptz` column.

*If you need to allow invalid values in `card_id` (really?), an FK constraint is not possible. There are other options:*

#### Only check new entries

You can "fake" an `IMMUTABLE` function that runs the check:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_card_allowed(text)
  RETURNS bool AS
$func$
SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM card_allowed WHERE card_allowed = $1);
$func$
  LANGUAGE sql STABLE;  -- not actually IMMUTABLE
```

The function is not *really* immutable, because it depends on values from another table. So it is actually only `STABLE`. The result of the same call can change between transactions. By definition [**`CHECK` constraints**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-CHECK-CONSTRAINTS) expect `IMMUTABLE` functions, but to allow some leeway (especially with temporal functions) `STABLE` is tolerated. You should mark the `CHECK` constraint as `NOT VALID` to document this, though:

```
ALTER TABLE client_1 ADD CONSTRAINT client_1_card_allowed
CHECK (f_card_allowed(card_id)) NOT VALID;
```

The difference: **Referential integrity is not enforced** at all times like with the FK constraint. Rows are only checked when inserted / updated and must be valid at this time. No promises are made as to the status of existing rows: you might have changed values in `card_allowed` by now. Details:

- [CONSTRAINT to check values from a remotely related table (via join etc.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27107034/constraint-to-check-values-from-a-remotely-related-table-via-join-etc/27107470#27107470)

#### Set the status *once*

Now you need the **additional flag `card_valid`** I commented out in the table definition above. You have ***no*** FK constraint:

```
UPDATE client_1 c
SET    card_valid = EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM card_allowed WHERE card_id = c.card_id);
```

#### Set the status after every change

You could do the same in a trigger function for every inserted / updated row:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trg_client_1_insupbef()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
   NEW.card_valid := EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM card_allowed WHERE card_id = NEW.card_id);
   RETURN NEW;
END
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER insupbef
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON client_1
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE trg_client_1_insupbef();
```