# Partial index on value from related table, rather than foreign key?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, constraints, postgresql-9.4

I'm working on a learning platform where students belong to a `team`, each of which belongs to a `curriculum`:

```
CREATE TABLE teams (
    id SERIAL,
    name string NOT NULL,
    curriculum_id integer NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE curricula (
    id SERIAL,
    name string NOT NULL
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_curricula_on_name ON curricula USING btree (name);
```

Curricula have to be unique by name, and while most curricula are allowed to have multiple teams associated to them, one can not. I am trying to add a partial (unique) index on the teams table so as to add a restraint on the curriculum.

I know I can partially constrain the curriculum id itself with...

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_teams_on_curriculum_id ON teams USING btree (curriculum_id)
WHERE curriculum_id = 1;
```

... but this is not viable, as the IDs for the curriculum will vary across environments (dev, staging, etc).

Is there a way to constrain the `teams.curriculum_id` column by `curricula.name` instead?

Comment: @erwin thanks for the edits and better tags!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could implement something like this with a trigger or with a fake immutable function in a `CHECK` constraint. Both have their weak spots.

But this can also be implemented with **pure SQL** - only using `NOT NULL`, `CHECK`, `UNIQUE` and `FK` constraints. No weak spot.

```
CREATE TABLE curriculum (
   curriculum_id serial PRIMARY KEY
 , curriculum    text UNIQUE NOT NULL
 , team_unique   boolean UNIQUE NOT NULL
 , CONSTRAINT curriculum_team_uni UNIQUE (curriculum_id, team_unique)  -- for multicolumn FK
);

CREATE TABLE team (
   team_id       serial PRIMARY KEY
 , team          text NOT NULL
 , curriculum_id integer NOT NULL
 , team_unique   boolean NOT NULL
 -- , CONSTRAINT fk1 FOREIGN KEY (curriculum_id) REFERENCES curriculum
 , CONSTRAINT fk2 FOREIGN KEY (curriculum_id, team_unique)
              REFERENCES curriculum (curriculum_id, team_unique)
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX team_curriculum_uni_idx ON team (team_unique)
WHERE team_unique;
```

- Add a `boolean NOT NULL` column to parent and child table and make it `UNIQUE` in the parent table. So only *one* row in `curriculum` can be marked unique - to implement your restrictive requirement:

  > one can not

  A partial unique index `team_curriculum_uni_idx` enforces only a single reference to it.

  If there were multiple unique curriculums (to be referenced once only), we would remove the `UNIQUE` constraints on `curriculum.team_unique` and extend the partial unique index on `team` to `(curriculum_id, team_unique)`.
- The FK (`fk2`) forces to inherit the combination of columns.
- This makes it simple to add a `UNIQUE` constraint to enforce a single team for the unique curriculum.
- The default `MATCH SIMPLE` behavior of Postgres FK constraints only enforces combinations without NULL values. We can either use `MATCH FULL` or another plain FK (`fk1`) to enforce only existing `curriculum_id`. I commented the additional FK since we don't need it in this configuration (both FK columns defined `NOT NULL`).

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/61404/1)

Related:

- [MATCH FULL vs MATCH SIMPLE in foreign key constraints](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/71508/3684)
- [CONSTRAINT to check values from a remotely related table (via join etc.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27107034/constraint-to-check-values-from-a-remotely-related-table-via-join-etc/27107470#27107470)
- [Disable all constraints and table checks while restoring a dump](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/75635/3684)
- [Enforcing constraints “two tables away”](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/58972/3684)

Comment: This is ridiculously phenomenal, thank you. It's going to be a bit before I can read through all of that and implement, but I wanted to thank you in advance.

Comment: @kevlarr: Note a minor simplification I added.