# Ensure data can only be changed by its actual owner in a database

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, security, database-design

## Background

We are building a new project and are currently 
at the database design. We 
stumbled upon a problem which
we cannot solve, we believe we
have some solutions to it but we are not sure. 
The problem seems a tad ungoogleable, 
probably because we don’t know enough
keywords on this topic.

## Problem

In our case we are building a rest-api
where a user authenticates with a token
to do CRUD-operations to the endpoints.

Thats alright, you need to provide a
valid token to access or modify a resource.
Standard stuff.

However, being authenticated does not prevent you from modifying rows 
that doesn’t belong to you.

Thus a user could possibly change other users data, 
since there is no logic that handles that. 
In the case a table is located far between each other, you cannot rely on foreign key or primary key constraints - unless see Solution 2.

### Solution 1

Add a field to every table that is either just a value holder or an actual fk.
That field references the primary key of the “owner” or user in our case.

### Solution 2

Take the performance hit and actually traverse
all the way back up to the "owner" of the
object/row.

### Solution 3

Implement a RLS (row level security) solution but
that does not seem to be the usecase for RLS or at least feels 
a bit to advanced for our usecase.

### Question

So the question is what is the most performant while still solving
the security issue? are there other solutions to this?

Solution 2 example:

### Tables

```
user
    id - pk
    … 

company 
    id - pk
    … 
    user_id - fk 

note
    id - pk
    … 
    user_id
```

### Session

```
user_session
    user_id
    …
```

### Data user can change:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    note
WHERE
    user_id = :session.user_id
```

### When user wants to update the data:

```
UPDATE note
SET text = “foobar”
WHERE user_id = :session.user_id AND id=payload.id
```

If there exists a row with user_id that corresponds
to the requesting user, and if the supplied primary key of the note
exists.

**References**

- [Constraint to check values from a remotely related table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27107034/constraint-to-check-values-from-a-remotely-related-table-via-join-etc#27107470)
- [Designing the most performant row level ..](https://medium.com/@cazzer/designing-the-most-performant-row-level-security-strategy-in-postgres-a06084f31945)
- [Application users vs. ro level security](https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/application-users-vs-row-level-security/)

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to decide your tenant strategy ("multi-tenancy" is your keyword). You can put user's data in different clusters, databases, schemas, or rows

Tenant-per-database is my preferred solution

> does not seem to be the usecase for RLS

This is absolutely a usecase for RLS

You'll want an "owner_id" column in each "secured" table. Ensure the current_user is that owner. Cascading foreign keys to update owner_id if it changes

You could use WITH CHECK OPTION views instead of RLS, but RLS is still simpler